# Oracle suggests TABLE ACCESS FULL after implementing SQL Profile

Tags: sql, oracle, indexing, profile, database-tuning-advisor

What I basically did was I used SQL Tuning Advisor for my long query. It suggested creating and SQL Profile which I did. 
I checked the performance of my query after the Profile was created, did not see much difference and decided to delete the Profile.
But now when I check the execution plan of the same query (for that I created and deleted the Profile) it shows Oracle ignores all indexes and performs only TABLE ACCESS FULL for all tables!
Do you know why is this happening?

It happens even if I slightly modify the query.
For other queries Oracle uses indexes as before.

I tried creating and dropping the Profile again, deleting the tuning task... but no difference.

EDIT: Sorry, I checked now the past execution plans and Oracle was performing full table scans before my experiments with sql profiles as well. I was wrong when I though I unintentionally changed something and did not know what.
Thanks for answers.

Comment: Sometimes full scans are the fastest thing there is. Without knowing much more about your query, tables, data layout, indexes & statistics, it's impossible to help you here.

Comment: I was going to ask, is it actually slower? And +1 to Mat's comment, sometimes indexes slow you down.

Comment: also confirm you don't have other baselines, SELECT SQL_HANDLE, SQL_TEXT, PLAN_NAME, ORIGIN,
       ENABLED, ACCEPTED
FROM   DBA_SQL_PLAN_BASELINES
WHERE  SQL_TEXT LIKE 'SELECT /* repeatable_sql%';

Comment: Full table scans are quite efficient when you are selecting more than 5% of the table rows. Nothing wrong with them. Do you think using an index is faster? Why?